# Daily cron at specific time on Openshift

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to run this script at 08:28am everyday, but it didn't work.How do I configure a daily job with a specific time?

```
#!/bin/bash
time=$(date +%H%M)
if [ $time -eq "0825" ]; then
php /var/lib/openshift/55375281e0b8cdb702000011/app-root/runtime/repo/php/test.php
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this in your minutely folder

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ `date +%H:%M` == "08:25" ]
then
######## do stuff here
fi
```

Comment: Thanks,it work. but I don't know why it only work 12 hours format, If I setting at "18:25" . It doesn't work.why ?

Comment: I am confused, `date +%H:%M` is server time or local time ? Because my local time is 18:25 , I have to setting at 06:25 then it will work.